# How to preallocate a list in Python 3.4?

Tags: python, python-3.4

I want to create a list of say 100 elements. How do I do that in Python 3.4. I tried to do the following.

```
l = None * [100]
```

but got the following error

```
TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'NoneType'
```

It works in Python 2.x but not Python 3.4.

I also tried `l = range[100]`, but it won't allow me to modify the elements afterwards.

Comment: No, it doesn't work in Python 2. It should be `l = [None] * 100`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are thinking of `l = [None] * 100`. ּּּּ`l = None * [100]ּ` is not valid in Python 2.x nor Python 3.x.